# Nginx identify domain in log files

Tags: nginx, access-log

I have set up nginx for some sites. In their .conf files, there can be server_name with multiple domains. However, when checking the log file, the domain name can't be identified. Is it possible to find out which domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can!

you should add $server_name in your log_format sentence. Could looks like

```
log_format compression '$server_name $remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                           '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                           '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$gzip_ratio"';
```

and after reload nginx you should be able to see the server name on your access log

Comment: Tks for answer, too bad i don't have permission to change the log_format

Comment: @nkt you could create your own format. And it's probably better to use $host variable